# DirectorySyncClientCmd.exe Missing from Windows Azure AD Sync

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, windows-server-2012, azure-active-directory

I recently installed Azure AD Connect on one of our servers to integrate with Office365. However when I attempt to do a manually sync with Command Prompt ("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure AD Sync\Bin\DirectorySyncClientCmd.exe" initial) I keep receiving an error "This app can't run on your PC".

Upon checking the directory I have noticed that the file is corrupt with a file size of 0kb.

I have re-ran the Azure AD Connect installer in repair mode hoping to restore this file however the file is not being repaired.

I am wondering if anyone knows what installer I could run to repair the file or if someone could upload a copy of the exe file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case someone hits this question in the future like I did, starting on Azure AD Connect version 1.1.105.0 they migrated the scheduler into the sync engine. You don't need the scheduled task, or DirectorySyncClientCmd.exe anymore.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnectsync-feature-scheduler/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-version-history/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by un-installing Azure AD Connect as well as its components and reinstalling it again without affecting the Active Directory.